# Major issue with running d3.v3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have made a html file based on: http://jsfiddle.net/kaliatech/4TMMD/
at the begning of my file, I have added:

```
<script src="data/d3.v3.js"></script>
<script src="data/nv.d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="data/nv.d3.js"></script>
<script src="data/tooltip.js"></script>
```

but I see this error: Error:

```
 Invalid value for <circle> attribute cx="NaN" d3.v3.js:663
    attrFunction.
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined d3.v3.js:4157
```

So the tooltip cannot be shown. How is it possible that d3.v3.js has this error! Why do I recieve this error?

Comment: What browser is this happening in? I've viewed your fiddle in Firefox and Chrome and don't see the error you mention.

Comment: what is cx ? what is undefined on 4157? something wrong in passing values

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am using chrome. cx referes to a function in d3.v3.js. and 4157 is the number of line in this file. and that is the function that leads to this error in this file: function attrFunction() {
      var x = value.apply(this, arguments);
      if (x == null) this.removeAttribute(name); else this.setAttribute(name, x);

Comment: Could you please tell me which script did you add and did you also download d3.v3.js? its strange that I see this error

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to add a charset attribute so that the utf-8 characters in d3.v3.js are decoded correctly by your browser.  This is the script tag recommended at http://d3js.org:

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```